# content_for button Rails Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, helper

I'm trying to translate a simple button into content_tag's for a Helper:

My Helper:

```
html = link_to disconnect_path(social: provider.downcase), class: "btn btn-#{provider.downcase} btn-block btn-social" do
  content_tag :i, 'Verified', class: "fa fa-#{provider.downcase}"
end
```

The button i need:

```
<a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook">
  <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Sign in with Facebook
</a>
```

The helper gets the 'Verified' inside the `i` tags ->

```
<i class="test">Verified</i>
```

but instead it should be outside ->

```
<i class="test"></i> Verified
```

Can anyone help me out setting this up ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Than move the title text outside of the i tag:

```
link_to(disconnect_path(social: provider.downcase), class: "btn btn-#{provider.downcase} btn-block btn-social") do
  content_tag(:i, '', class: "fa fa-#{provider.downcase}") + 'Verified'
end
```